# spark.read.format('libsvm') not working with python

Tags: jupyter, pyspark

I am learning `PYSPARK` and encountered a problem that I can't fix. I followed this video to copy codes from the `PYSPARK` documentation to load data for linear regression. The code I got from the documentation was spark.read.format('libsvm').load('file.txt'). I created a spark data frame before this btw. When I run this code in `Jupyter` notebook it keeps giving me some java error and the guy in this video did the exact same thing as I did and he didn't get this error. Can someone help me resolve this issue, please?
A lot of thanks!

Comment: what kind of java error you are getting? Can copy and paste the exact stack trace in the question only.

Comment: I am getting An error occurred while calling o65. load. java.lang.UnsupportedOperationExeption: empty collection. I think this is because of the format. In the video, format was a keyword appeared in green color but it's black in my file.

Answer (score 5):

I think I solved this issue by setting the "numFeatures" in the option method:

```
 training = spark.read.format('libsvm').option("numFeatures","10").load('sample_linear_regression_data.txt', header=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this custom function to read libsvm file.

```
from pyspark.sql import Row
from pyspark.ml.linalg import SparseVector

def read_libsvm(filepath, spark_session):
    '''
    A utility function that takes in a libsvm file and turn it to a pyspark dataframe.

    Args:
        filepath (str): The file path to the data file.
        spark_session (object): The SparkSession object to create dataframe.

    Returns:
        A pyspark dataframe that contains the data loaded.
    '''

    with open(filepath, 'r') as f:
        raw_data = [x.split() for x in f.readlines()]

    outcome = [int(x[0]) for x in raw_data]

    index_value_dict = list()
    for row in raw_data:
        index_value_dict.append(dict([(int(x.split(':')[0]), float(x.split(':')[1]))
                                       for x in row[1:]]))

    max_idx = max([max(x.keys()) for x in index_value_dict])
    rows = [
        Row(
            label=outcome[i],
            feat_vector=SparseVector(max_idx + 1, index_value_dict[i])
        )
        for i in range(len(index_value_dict))
    ]
    df = spark_session.createDataFrame(rows)
    return df
```

**Usage:**

```
my_data = read_libsvm(filepath="sample_libsvm_data.txt", spark_session=spark)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try to load via:

```
from pyspark.mllib.util import MLUtils
df = MLUtils.loadLibSVMFile(sc,"data.libsvm",numFeatures=781).toDF()
```

`sc` is Spark context and `df` is resulting data frame.